# Windows Server Backup - Please wait

Tags: windows, backup, windows-server-backup

I have an annoying issue with Windows Server Backup - Please wait...

I added one RAID 5 array and reconfigured some drives and changed letters of non system drives, after which I couldn't start Server Backup GUI.

Then I reinstalled Server Backup and ran CMD as admin and then `wbadmin delete catalog` and deleted log files, which enabled me to run wbadmin GUI again.

However, when I clicked "Backup Schedule..." I get "Please wait..." and nothing. I have been watching this for at least 30 minutes now.

I would highly appreciate if someone could hop on and help me solve this, because this is backup for our main server.

Thanks!

Comment: What does the eventlog>application say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all. After a lot of trying, it turned out that the Server Backup was looking for a disk that wasn't there AND it tried to do something (I suppose enumerate backups) with old backup USB disk.

I had trouble disabling the drive, and in the end I disabled the device in device manager. After that everything magically started working fine.

So, the issue was fixed by removing old drives (disabling or physical remove will work). I am fairly certain this issue is what others had.